# New USB optical mouse not working on ubuntu 17.04 (HP X1500)

Tags: usb, mouse, thinkpad

I bought a new mouse (HP X1500) to work on my Thinkpad p51.
When I plugged it in it is recognzized by

> lsusb

I have looked around but nothing seems to work.
Is there anything in ubuntu that blocks usb devices to be recognized as mouse device?

Comment: Go to System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad, inspect it

Comment: I can see the settings, but I cannot select the device there.